# Сайт отвечает ошибкой 500 только с одного устройства

Tags: http, сеть, dns

При попытке зайти на сайт (сторонний) получаю ответ http error 500. Проблема воспроизводится только на одном устройстве с windows 10. Причем если заходить с включенным vpn (расширение Browsec для firefox) - то всё нормально. С других устройств в этой же wi-fi сети тоже всё нормально.
Комп/роутер перезагружал, чистил кэш браузера и днс (ipconfig /flushdns) - безрезультатно

```
curl 'https://animego.org/' \
  -H 'authority: animego.org' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'cookie: __ddg1_=YrollqjIPSZKy5gfneCs' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: на другом устройстве с win10 пробовали?

Comment: Да, всё нормально загружается. Единственная разница - проблемное устройство подключено напрямую к роутеру (стационарный ПК)

Comment: Проанализируйте отправляемые заголовки, и добавьте их в вопрос, гадать на кофейной гуще сложно.

Comment: так как это внутренняя ошибка сервера, то и дебажить нужно сам сервер, смотреть что идет с 10-ки на сервер сравнивать с остальными сообщениями, сайт сторонний - решения нет

Comment: на всякий случай объясню почему я считаю что решения нет (для стороннего сайта) ошибка происходит в коде на сервере, и совершенно не понятна из-за чего, но общая причина то что сервер готовит ответ для клиента, а запрос от клиента формируется не Вами в ручную а кодом клиентской части (его Вы тоже поменять не можете) расширение Browsec возможно урезает какие-то куки или подменяет IP тоже нужно знать что оно делает что влияет на результат

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась очень банальной. Несколько недель назад подключался через wireguard к Нидерландскому VPN. И забыл про него вообще, думал что отключился. А он так и продолжал каждый раз подключаться к нему. Отключился - и всё заработало